# MEAN Stack App: Can not get my routes right

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I am currently creating a simple application using the MEAN stack and I can not get my routes correct. The localhost:3000 brings me to the 404 page. Also when I go to localhost:3000 the root path should be localhost:3000/#/home and it should display the posts. I believe it is a problem with my routes because the posts are showing up, if I go to localhost:3000/posts it lists the posts in JSON format. I want the root index to display the posts but not in JSON format.

Here is there error that prints out on the page.

```
 at /Users/ipbyrne/flapper-news-1stattempt/app.js:36:13
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/ipbyrne/flapper-news-
1stattempt/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/ipbyrne/flapper-news-1stattempt/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /Users/ipbyrne/flapper-news-1stattempt/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/ipbyrne/flapper-news-1stattempt/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/Users/ipbyrne/flapper-news-1stattempt/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at /Users/ipbyrne/flapper-news-1stattempt/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:618:15
    at next (/Users/ipbyrne/flapper-news-1stattempt/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:256:14)
    at Function.handle (/Users/ipbyrne/flapper-news-1stattempt/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
    at router (/Users/ipbyrne/flapper-news-1stattempt/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/ipbyrne/flapper-news-1stattempt/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/ipbyrne/flapper-news-1stattempt/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /Users/ipbyrne/flapper-news-1stattempt/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/ipbyrne/flapper-news-1stattempt/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/Users/ipbyrne/flapper-news-1stattempt/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at SendStream.error (/Users/ipbyrne/flapper-news-1stattempt/node_modules/express/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:120:7)
```

Here is my app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('./models/Posts');
require('./models/Comments');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/news');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found :(');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

And here is my routes file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');

router.get('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
  Post.find(function(err, posts){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(posts);
  });
});

router.post('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
  var post = new Post(req.body);

  post.save(function(err, post){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(post);
  });
});

router.param('post', function(req, res, next, id) {
  var query = Post.findById(id);

  query.exec(function (err, post) {
    if(err){return next(err);}
    if(!post){return next(new Error('can\'t find post')); }

    req.post = post;
    return next();
  });
});
router.param('comment', function(req, res, next, id) {
  var query = Comment.findById(id);

  query.exec(function (err, comment) {
    if(err){return next(err);}
    if(!comment){return next(new Error('can\'t find comment')); }

    req.comment = comment;
    return next();
  });
});

router.get('/posts/:post', function(req, res, next) {
  req.post.populate('comments', function(err, post) {
    if(err) {return next(err);}

    res.json(req.post);
  });
});

router.put('/posts/:post/upvote', function(req, res, next) {
  req.post.upvote(function(err, post) {
    if(err) {return next(err) }

    res.json(post);
  });
});

router.put('/posts/:post/comments/:comment/upvote', function(req, 

res, next) {

  req.comment.upvote(function(err, comment) {
    if(err) {return next(err) }

    res.json(comment);
  });
});

router.post('/posts/:post/comments', function(req, res, next) {
  var comment = new Comment(req.body);
  comment.post = req.post;

  comment.save(function(err, comment) {
    if(err){return next(err); }

    req.post.comments.push(comment);
    req.post.save(function(err, post) {
      if(err){return next(err);}

      res.json(comment);
    });
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Any input on how I may resolve this will be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if there are any other files you need to say that can help in resolving the problem also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Here is there error that prints out on the page."* you missed the error message, which should be a couple lines above that output.

Comment: This is the text above all the stuff i put `Not Found :(

404

Error: Not Found :( `

Comment: and that's too far above.

Comment: That with the text in the post is everything the page prints out.

Comment: The problem is of course you never defined a route for `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a 404 error because Express can't find the route in the "routes" sub app. Try to add the following to ./routes/index:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.json({route: 'this is the home page'});
});
```

In case you would like to receive a html page, put this in app.js:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render("home.html");
});
```

Comment: After doing this I just get JSON out put `{
route: "this is the home page"
}` at my localhost:3000

Comment: how about create a new file called "home.html" and use the second snippet in app.js :)